# How to rectify module deployment error while using GlassFish Server?

Tags: java, jsf, glassfish

How to rectify module deployment error while using GlassFish Server?

While trying to run jsf web-application in  Netbeans8   I am getting the following error:

```
ant -f C:\\Users\\admin\\Desktop\\WebTime -Dnb.internal.action.name=run -Ddirectory.deployment.supported=true -DforceRedeploy=false -Dnb.wait.for.caches=true -Dbrowser.context=C:\\Users\\admin\\Desktop\\WebTime run
init:
deps-module-jar:
deps-ear-jar:
deps-jar:
library-inclusion-in-archive:
library-inclusion-in-manifest:
compile:
compile-jsps:
Starting GlassFish Server
GlassFish Server is running.
In-place deployment at C:\Users\admin\Desktop\WebTime\build\web
GlassFish Server, deploy, Connection refused: connect, false
C:\Users\admin\Desktop\WebTime\nbproject\build-impl.xml:1045: The module has not been deployed. See the server log for details.
```

Being new to programming, I need hint to rectify this error. Kindly help me to rectify it.

Answer (score 7):

The line:

`GlassFish Server, deploy, Connection refused: connect, false`

... is a clue.

I had the same error, but I solved it. The steps:

1) Grant privileges to write on the glassfish server installation folder. If you use Windows the path is: 
**C:\Program Files\glassfish-xx**

2) Run **C:\Program Files\glassfish-xx\bin\asadmin.bat** as Administrator. Then in the console type: `start-domain`

3) Clean and Build the project

4) Deploy

5) Run

PD: I recommend use JDK7

Comment: I did this but didn't succeed in deploying my application. So I instead ran the command `delete-domain <domain_name>`. In my case the domain name was domain1. Then I recreated the domain `create-domain <domain-name>`. Making sure that I place my properties file to the `domains/<domain-name>/lib/classes` folder and my database driver to `domains/<domain-name>/lib/ext` folder. I copied these two files to a temporal directory out of the domain before deleting it.

Answer (score 2):

after a whole day solving this problem on my own, because nobody's answer was usefull for me on internet, I found following:

1. don't try to use different web server (I tried wildfly), it wont
   help.
2. give glassfish folder permission to write (I mean the folder with
   version in name)
3. restart pc to shut down all (or the) running server
4. after my restart, I got still the same error during developing  `build-impl.xml:1045: The module has not been deployed.`, but now there was different error in server log - `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid URL Pattern: [{0}]`.
5. Then I realised that my problem was in web.xml file, where I tried to set different welcome page. All other projects with this file untouched were working (developing, running) properly

so this was my story of waisting whole day - **check your web.xml file**

Answer (score 0):

> Being new to programming, I need hint to rectify this error. Kindly
>   help me to rectify it.

If you look carefully, the hint is given in the output itself.

```
See the server log for details.
```

In NetBeans IDE output's sub-window, you should see another tab called "GlassFish Server", you can look there for logs from the server.

Alternatively , you can use GlassFish's Administration GUI to see some more detailed logs, it is accessible in a browser and by default from localhost:4848.

> While trying to run jsf web-application in Netbeans8 I am getting the
>   following error:

Looking at what you have posted (project's deployment log), I can say your GlassFish instance is running fine , but your project contains errors, so it couldn't be deployed.

I doubt anyone here can concretely solve your problem because we need more details from GlassFish's logs.

Suggestion : Edit your question by appending GlassFish's logs.