# NetBeans Tomcat build failed - The module has not been deployed

Tags: java, apache, tomcat, netbeans

I am using NetBeans 8.0 and using Apache Tomcat 7.0.56 to build a web application.

I am trying to run a simple HTML file `groceryPage.html` and keep getting the following error:

> In-place deployment at C:\Users\HP\Documents\CS3160_Lab3\build\web
>   Deployment is in progress...
>   deploy?config=file%3A%2FC%3A%2FUsers%2FHP%2FAppData%2FLocal%2FTemp%2Fcontext8713751033956149596.xml&path=/CS3160_Lab3
>   FAIL - Unable to create directory [C:\Program
>   Files\Java\apache-tomcat-7.0.56\conf\Catalina\localhost]
>   C:\Users\HP\Documents\CS3160_Lab3\nbproject\build-impl.xml:1045: The
>   module has not been deployed. See the server log for details. BUILD
>   FAILED (total time: 1 second)

I am fairly new to using Tomcat and NetBeans so I don't really know why it doesn't successfully build and run my app

Any help would be appreciated.

**EDIT**

Here is the server log, if it may help:

```
Using CATALINA_BASE:   "C:\Program Files\Java\apache-tomcat-7.0.56"
Using CATALINA_HOME:   "C:\Program Files\Java\apache-tomcat-7.0.56"
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: "C:\Program Files\Java\apache-tomcat-7.0.56\temp"
Using JRE_HOME:        "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_40"
Using CLASSPATH:       "C:\Program Files\Java\apache-tomcat-7.0.56\bin\bootstrap.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\apache-tomcat-7.0.56\bin\tomcat-juli.jar"
java.util.logging.ErrorManager: 4
java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Program Files\Java\apache-tomcat-7.0.56\logs\catalina.2014-11-24.log (Access is denied)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:221)
    at org.apache.juli.FileHandler.openWriter(FileHandler.java:386)
    at org.apache.juli.FileHandler.<init>(FileHandler.java:97)
    at org.apache.juli.FileHandler.<init>(FileHandler.java:88)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:374)
    at org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager.readConfiguration(ClassLoaderLogManager.java:558)
    at org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager.readConfiguration(ClassLoaderLogManager.java:501)
    at org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager.readConfiguration(ClassLoaderLogManager.java:311)
    at java.util.logging.LogManager$2.run(LogManager.java:294)
    at java.util.logging.LogManager$2.run(LogManager.java:292)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.util.logging.LogManager.readPrimordialConfiguration(LogManager.java:292)
    at java.util.logging.LogManager.getLogManager(LogManager.java:274)
    at java.util.logging.Logger.<init>(Logger.java:264)
    at java.util.logging.Logger.<init>(Logger.java:260)
    at java.util.logging.LogManager$RootLogger.<init>(LogManager.java:1412)
    at java.util.logging.LogManager$RootLogger.<init>(LogManager.java:1410)
    at java.util.logging.LogManager$1.run(LogManager.java:196)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.util.logging.LogManager.<clinit>(LogManager.java:173)
    at java.util.logging.Logger.demandLogger(Logger.java:336)
    at java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Logger.java:390)
    at org.apache.juli.logging.DirectJDKLog.<init>(DirectJDKLog.java:71)
    at org.apache.juli.logging.DirectJDKLog.getInstance(DirectJDKLog.java:196)
    at org.apache.juli.logging.LogFactory.getInstance(LogFactory.java:169)
    at org.apache.juli.logging.LogFactory.getInstance(LogFactory.java:241)
    at org.apache.juli.logging.LogFactory.getLog(LogFactory.java:292)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.<clinit>(Bootstrap.java:59)
java.util.logging.ErrorManager: 4
java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Program Files\Java\apache-tomcat-7.0.56\logs\localhost.2014-11-24.log (Access is denied)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:221)
    at org.apache.juli.FileHandler.openWriter(FileHandler.java:386)
    at org.apache.juli.FileHandler.<init>(FileHandler.java:97)
    at org.apache.juli.FileHandler.<init>(FileHandler.java:88)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:374)
    at org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager.readConfiguration(ClassLoaderLogManager.java:558)
    at org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager.readConfiguration(ClassLoaderLogManager.java:501)
    at org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager.readConfiguration(ClassLoaderLogManager.java:311)
    at java.util.logging.LogManager$2.run(LogManager.java:294)
    at java.util.logging.LogManager$2.run(LogManager.java:292)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.util.logging.LogManager.readPrimordialConfiguration(LogManager.java:292)
    at java.util.logging.LogManager.getLogManager(LogManager.java:274)
    at java.util.logging.Logger.<init>(Logger.java:264)
    at java.util.logging.Logger.<init>(Logger.java:260)
    at java.util.logging.LogManager$RootLogger.<init>(LogManager.java:1412)
    at java.util.logging.LogManager$RootLogger.<init>(LogManager.java:1410)
    at java.util.logging.LogManager$1.run(LogManager.java:196)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.util.logging.LogManager.<clinit>(LogManager.java:173)
    at java.util.logging.Logger.demandLogger(Logger.java:336)
    at java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Logger.java:390)
    at org.apache.juli.logging.DirectJDKLog.<init>(DirectJDKLog.java:71)
    at org.apache.juli.logging.DirectJDKLog.getInstance(DirectJDKLog.java:196)
    at org.apache.juli.logging.LogFactory.getInstance(LogFactory.java:169)
    at org.apache.juli.logging.LogFactory.getInstance(LogFactory.java:241)
    at org.apache.juli.logging.LogFactory.getLog(LogFactory.java:292)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.<clinit>(Bootstrap.java:59)
java.util.logging.ErrorManager: 4
java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Program Files\Java\apache-tomcat-7.0.56\logs\manager.2014-11-24.log (Access is denied)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:221)
    at org.apache.juli.FileHandler.openWriter(FileHandler.java:386)
    at org.apache.juli.FileHandler.<init>(FileHandler.java:97)
    at org.apache.juli.FileHandler.<init>(FileHandler.java:88)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:374)
    at org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager.readConfiguration(ClassLoaderLogManager.java:558)
    at org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager.readConfiguration(ClassLoaderLogManager.java:501)
    at org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager.readConfiguration(ClassLoaderLogManager.java:311)
    at java.util.logging.LogManager$2.run(LogManager.java:294)
    at java.util.logging.LogManager$2.run(LogManager.java:292)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.util.logging.LogManager.readPrimordialConfiguration(LogManager.java:292)
    at java.util.logging.LogManager.getLogManager(LogManager.java:274)
    at java.util.logging.Logger.<init>(Logger.java:264)
    at java.util.logging.Logger.<init>(Logger.java:260)
    at java.util.logging.LogManager$RootLogger.<init>(LogManager.java:1412)
    at java.util.logging.LogManager$RootLogger.<init>(LogManager.java:1410)
    at java.util.logging.LogManager$1.run(LogManager.java:196)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.util.logging.LogManager.<clinit>(LogManager.java:173)
    at java.util.logging.Logger.demandLogger(Logger.java:336)
    at java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Logger.java:390)
    at org.apache.juli.logging.DirectJDKLog.<init>(DirectJDKLog.java:71)
    at org.apache.juli.logging.DirectJDKLog.getInstance(DirectJDKLog.java:196)
    at org.apache.juli.logging.LogFactory.getInstance(LogFactory.java:169)
    at org.apache.juli.logging.LogFactory.getInstance(LogFactory.java:241)
    at org.apache.juli.logging.LogFactory.getLog(LogFactory.java:292)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.<clinit>(Bootstrap.java:59)
java.util.logging.ErrorManager: 4
java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Program Files\Java\apache-tomcat-7.0.56\logs\host-manager.2014-11-24.log (Access is denied)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:221)
    at org.apache.juli.FileHandler.openWriter(FileHandler.java:386)
    at org.apache.juli.FileHandler.<init>(FileHandler.java:97)
    at org.apache.juli.FileHandler.<init>(FileHandler.java:88)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:374)
    at org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager.readConfiguration(ClassLoaderLogManager.java:558)
    at org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager.readConfiguration(ClassLoaderLogManager.java:501)
    at org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager.readConfiguration(ClassLoaderLogManager.java:311)
    at java.util.logging.LogManager$2.run(LogManager.java:294)
    at java.util.logging.LogManager$2.run(LogManager.java:292)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.util.logging.LogManager.readPrimordialConfiguration(LogManager.java:292)
    at java.util.logging.LogManager.getLogManager(LogManager.java:274)
    at java.util.logging.Logger.<init>(Logger.java:264)
    at java.util.logging.Logger.<init>(Logger.java:260)
    at java.util.logging.LogManager$RootLogger.<init>(LogManager.java:1412)
    at java.util.logging.LogManager$RootLogger.<init>(LogManager.java:1410)
    at java.util.logging.LogManager$1.run(LogManager.java:196)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.util.logging.LogManager.<clinit>(LogManager.java:173)
    at java.util.logging.Logger.demandLogger(Logger.java:336)
    at java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Logger.java:390)
    at org.apache.juli.logging.DirectJDKLog.<init>(DirectJDKLog.java:71)
    at org.apache.juli.logging.DirectJDKLog.getInstance(DirectJDKLog.java:196)
    at org.apache.juli.logging.LogFactory.getInstance(LogFactory.java:169)
    at org.apache.juli.logging.LogFactory.getInstance(LogFactory.java:241)
    at org.apache.juli.logging.LogFactory.getLog(LogFactory.java:292)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.<clinit>(Bootstrap.java:59)
Nov 24, 2014 11:34:23 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
INFO: Loaded APR based Apache Tomcat Native library 1.1.31 using APR version 1.4.8.
Nov 24, 2014 11:34:23 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
INFO: APR capabilities: IPv6 [true], sendfile [true], accept filters [false], random [true].
Nov 24, 2014 11:34:25 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener initializeSSL
INFO: OpenSSL successfully initialized (OpenSSL 1.0.1h 5 Jun 2014)
Nov 24, 2014 11:34:25 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-apr-8080"]
Nov 24, 2014 11:34:25 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-apr-8009"]
Nov 24, 2014 11:34:25 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 2194 ms
Nov 24, 2014 11:34:25 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Catalina
Nov 24, 2014 11:34:25 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.56
Nov 24, 2014 11:34:25 PM org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve open
SEVERE: Failed to open access log file [C:\Program Files\Java\apache-tomcat-7.0.56\logs\localhost_access_log.2014-11-24.txt]
java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Program Files\Java\apache-tomcat-7.0.56\logs\localhost_access_log.2014-11-24.txt (Access is denied)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:221)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.open(AccessLogValve.java:1200)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.startInternal(AccessLogValve.java:1261)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.startInternal(StandardPipeline.java:185)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1137)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:816)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1575)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1565)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)

Nov 24, 2014 11:34:25 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig start
SEVERE: Unable to create directory for deployment: C:\Program Files\Java\apache-tomcat-7.0.56\conf\Catalina\localhost
Nov 24, 2014 11:34:25 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory C:\Program Files\Java\apache-tomcat-7.0.56\webapps\docs
Nov 24, 2014 11:34:25 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext postWorkDirectory
WARNING: Failed to create work directory [C:\Program Files\Java\apache-tomcat-7.0.56\work\Catalina\localhost\docs] for context [/docs]
Nov 24, 2014 11:34:26 PM org.apache.jasper.EmbeddedServletOptions <init>
SEVERE: The scratchDir you specified: C:\Program Files\Java\apache-tomcat-7.0.56\work\Catalina\localhost\docs is unusable.
Nov 24, 2014 11:34:26 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deployment of web application directory C:\Program Files\Java\apache-tomcat-7.0.56\webapps\docs has finished in 773 ms
Nov 24, 2014 11:34:26 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory C:\Program Files\Java\apache-tomcat-7.0.56\webapps\examples
Nov 24, 2014 11:34:26 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext postWorkDirectory
WARNING: Failed to create work directory [C:\Program Files\Java\apache-tomcat-7.0.56\work\Catalina\localhost\examples] for context [/examples]
Nov 24, 2014 11:34:27 PM org.apache.jasper.EmbeddedServletOptions <init>
SEVERE: The scratchDir you specified: C:\Program Files\Java\apache-tomcat-7.0.56\work\Catalina\localhost\examples is unusable.
Nov 24, 2014 11:34:27 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deployment of web application directory C:\Program Files\Java\apache-tomcat-7.0.56\webapps\examples has finished in 707 ms
Nov 24, 2014 11:34:27 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory C:\Program Files\Java\apache-tomcat-7.0.56\webapps\host-manager
Nov 24, 2014 11:34:27 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext postWorkDirectory
WARNING: Failed to create work directory [C:\Program Files\Java\apache-tomcat-7.0.56\work\Catalina\localhost\host-manager] for context [/host-manager]
Nov 24, 2014 11:34:27 PM org.apache.jasper.EmbeddedServletOptions <init>
SEVERE: The scratchDir you specified: C:\Program Files\Java\apache-tomcat-7.0.56\work\Catalina\localhost\host-manager is unusable.
Nov 24, 2014 11:34:27 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deployment of web application directory C:\Program Files\Java\apache-tomcat-7.0.56\webapps\host-manager has finished in 113 ms
Nov 24, 2014 11:34:27 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory C:\Program Files\Java\apache-tomcat-7.0.56\webapps\manager
Nov 24, 2014 11:34:27 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext postWorkDirectory
WARNING: Failed to create work directory [C:\Program Files\Java\apache-tomcat-7.0.56\work\Catalina\localhost\manager] for context [/manager]
Nov 24, 2014 11:34:27 PM org.apache.jasper.EmbeddedServletOptions <init>
SEVERE: The scratchDir you specified: C:\Program Files\Java\apache-tomcat-7.0.56\work\Catalina\localhost\manager is unusable.
Nov 24, 2014 11:34:27 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deployment of web application directory C:\Program Files\Java\apache-tomcat-7.0.56\webapps\manager has finished in 104 ms
Nov 24, 2014 11:34:27 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory C:\Program Files\Java\apache-tomcat-7.0.56\webapps\ROOT
Nov 24, 2014 11:34:27 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext postWorkDirectory
WARNING: Failed to create work directory [C:\Program Files\Java\apache-tomcat-7.0.56\work\Catalina\localhost\_] for context []
Nov 24, 2014 11:34:27 PM org.apache.jasper.EmbeddedServletOptions <init>
SEVERE: The scratchDir you specified: C:\Program Files\Java\apache-tomcat-7.0.56\work\Catalina\localhost\_ is unusable.
Nov 24, 2014 11:34:27 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deployment of web application directory C:\Program Files\Java\apache-tomcat-7.0.56\webapps\ROOT has finished in 109 ms
Nov 24, 2014 11:34:27 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-apr-8080"]
Nov 24, 2014 11:34:27 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-apr-8009"]
Nov 24, 2014 11:34:27 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 1926 ms
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It clearly says, `Access is denied`.

Make sure directory and file `C:\Program Files\Java\apache-tomcat-7.0.56\logs\catalina.2014-11-24.log` is writable for the user who is running Tomcat.

Comment: I have no file like `C:\Program Files\Java\apache-tomcat-7.0.56\logs\catalina.2014-11-24.log`, what do I do? The `logs` folder is empty

Comment: That's the point, file in this folder can not be created. Is this folder writable for the user which is running Tomcat?

Comment: Solved! I changed the permissions for the logs folder in windows explorer to allow write permissions.

Answer (score 1):

The problem can be occur because of your `proxy` settings. If you set manual `proxy` on your computer, make sure that `netbeans` also setup with the **same** **proxy** settings.(Tool > Options > Proxy Settings)

Answer (score 1):

If you are running on a Windows machine, make sure that you right click the menu option to start Netbeans and select 'Run as Administrator'.  This should solve your access issue.

Answer (score 0):

you can try to search for my sollution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24536907/how-to-rectify-module-deployment-error-while-using-glassfish-server/38686925#38686925).
basically just give write permission to glassfish folder and restart your pc, optionally revert changes in web.xml file

Answer (score 0):

Change the owner of the directory of Tomcat. On Linux or BSD do this:

chown -R username /usr/local/apache-tomcat-8.0/

*check which directory is the Tomcat on your distro.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this, changing the properties of the folder from the path from apache installation so.
1. right click over folder from apache tomcat 
2. Select properties 
3. Give full control in the tab security for all users or my user that going to publish the war or develop with NetBeans.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this similar error by carefully reading the "Apache Tomcat Server log".
Your IDE should be able to cleanly display it for you.
It taught me to always first read the logs when looking for the culprit.

For me, it was deploying using the `@WebServlet` annotation and the **web.xml** deployment descriptor at the same time for the same Servlet. Yet i had to choose one of the 2 options.

Whatever it maybe for your case, ALWAYS **DON'T** be afraid to read the Server logs. That is where all clues reside.