# build-impl.xml : 1052 :The module has not been deployed. See the server log for details

Tags: spring, hibernate, glassfish-4

I have seen all answers from stackoverflow and tried each one of them but not able to solve this error as mentioned below (glassfish 4).

> Exception while deploying the app [SpirngDemo] :
>   org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 13; columnNumber: 53;
>   Deployment descriptor file WEB-INF/web.xml in archive [web]. 
>   cvc-complex-type.2.3: Element 'welcome-file-list' cannot have
>   character [children], because the type's content type is element-only.
>   org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 13; columnNumber: 53;
>   Deployment descriptor file WEB-INF/web.xml in archive [web]. 
>   cvc-complex-type.2.3: Element 'welcome-file-list' cannot have
>   character [children], because the type's content type is element-only.
>     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.deployment.io.DeploymentDescriptorFile.read(DeploymentDescriptorFile.java:324)
>     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.deployment.io.DeploymentDescriptorFile.read(DeploymentDescriptorFile.java:245)
>     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.deployment.archivist.Archivist.readStandardDeploymentDescriptor(Archivist.java:665)
>     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.deployment.archivist.Archivist.readDeploymentDescriptors(Archivist.java:391)
>     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.deployment.archivist.Archivist.open(Archivist.java:271)
>     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.deployment.archivist.Archivist.open(Archivist.java:280)
>     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.deployment.archivist.Archivist.open(Archivist.java:241)
>     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.deployment.archivist.ApplicationFactory.openArchive(ApplicationFactory.java:161)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.javaee.core.deployment.DolProvider.processDOL(DolProvider.java:198)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.javaee.core.deployment.DolProvider.load(DolProvider.java:222)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.javaee.core.deployment.DolProvider.load(DolProvider.java:96)
>     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.loadDeployer(ApplicationLifecycle.java:878)
>     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.setupContainerInfos(ApplicationLifecycle.java:818)
>     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:374)
>     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:219)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:491)
>     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:527)
>     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:523)
>     at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)   at
>   javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:360)    at
>   com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:522)
>     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:546)
>     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1423)
>     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$1500(CommandRunnerImpl.java:108)
>     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1762)
>     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1674)
>     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.doCommand(AdminAdapter.java:534)
>     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.onMissingResource(AdminAdapter.java:224)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.StaticHttpHandler.service(StaticHttpHandler.java:297)
>     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:246)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:191)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:168)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:189)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:288)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:206)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:136)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:114)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:838)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:113)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:115)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:55)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:135)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:564)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:544)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) Caused by:
>   org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 13; columnNumber: 53;
>   cvc-complex-type.2.3: Element 'welcome-file-list' cannot have
>   character [children], because the type's content type is element-only.
>     at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:203)
>     at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.error(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:134)
>     at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:437)
>     at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:368)
>     at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:325)
>     at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator$XSIErrorReporter.reportError(XMLSchemaValidator.java:458)
>     at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.reportSchemaError(XMLSchemaValidator.java:3237)
>     at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.elementLocallyValidComplexType(XMLSchemaValidator.java:3200)
>     at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.elementLocallyValidType(XMLSchemaValidator.java:3160)
>     at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.processElementContent(XMLSchemaValidator.java:3062)
>     at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.handleEndElement(XMLSchemaValidator.java:2140)
>     at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.endElement(XMLSchemaValidator.java:859)
>     at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanEndElement(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:1782)
>     at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:2973)
>     at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:606)
>     at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:117)
>     at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:510)
>     at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:848)
>     at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:777)
>     at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:141)
>     at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1213)
>     at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:649)
>     at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:333)
>     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.deployment.io.DeploymentDescriptorFile.read(DeploymentDescriptorFile.java:318)
>     ... 46 more ]]

This is MY **web.xml** file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.htm</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
            30
        </session-timeout>
    </session-config>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>redirect.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

thanks in advance.

Comment: I guess the people should guess what the problem is?

Comment: following link may help people for more information and i have applied this all solutions as mentioned above 1>>>http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22573787/apache-tomcat-7-0-14build-impl-xml1111-the-module-has-not-been-deployed. 2>>>>http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16400810/build-impl-xml1031-the-module-has-not-%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Bbeen-deployed  3>>>http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20976377/deployment-error-java-webproject-from-netbeans-to-glassfish-4-0. 4>>>http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27115614/netbeans-tomcat-build-failed-the-module-has-not-been-deployed.

Comment: What you are doing doesn't make sense...if you want help you have to update the question (don't post comments) with the contents of your `server.log`....

Comment: okay. As above is error am getting while running my project and i am unable to open server log file. so what else can i update. ? else tell me what exactly is required here ?

Comment: The content of the `server.log` is required...how can you be unable to open this file? Fix that...

Comment: i have got that log file but how i can display(upload) here ? is this an issue from database side ?

Comment: Click edit on your question and copy the text from the file to the input field...

Comment: It looks like there is a problem with your `web.xml`.  Please add this add this file to the question.

Comment: is there anything i need to change ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't tell you exactly what the problem is but the error message indicates that there is something wrong with your `web.xml`.

This part of the error message

> Deployment descriptor file WEB-INF/web.xml in archive [web].
>   cvc-complex-type.2.3: Element 'welcome-file-list' cannot have
>   character [children], because the type's content type is element-only.

indicates a problem in this section:

```
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>redirect.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

but there is nothing wrong with this. Are you sure that exactly this error occurs in your `server.log` when you deploy you application with this `web.xml`?

This error occurs sometimes when there are "invalid" characters like ">" as text content in XML files, here is an example:

```
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>>redirect.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

The double ">" on the opening welcome-file tag is considered as data (the value) and this data must not contain characters like ">" and "<" (and some more).

So, to fix the problem, double-check that your XML files are valid (you can also pre-validate them inside your IDE), if they are, there should be a different error message in your `server.log`.